# Static drupal 7 query to dynamic query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-7

I need to take agent_name, count(id), ifs_code, area_code.

When I use static query all work fine:

```
$result = db_query('SELECT agent_name, count(id) as count, ifs_code, area_code FROM declarations WHERE fisccode = :idno GROUP BY agent_name', array(':idno' => $fisccode))->fetchAll();
```

Result from this query:

```
/report5.inc:82: array (size=1) 0 => object(stdClass)[10] public 'agent_name' => string 'GHEOLARIS S.A' (length=13) public 'count' => string '3' (length=1) public 'ifs_code' => string '02' (length=2) public 'area_code' => string '0110' (length=4)
```

---

But I dont understand how to take **count(id) as count** in dynamic query.

I try this:

```
$result = db_select('declarations', 'd')
      ->fields('d', array('agent_name', 'ifs_code', 'area_code'))
      ->addExpression('COUNT(id)', 'count') // I THINK I DO SOMETHING WRONG ON THIS LINE
      ->condition('fisccode', $fisccode)
      ->groupBy('agent_name')
      ->range($context['sandbox']['progress'], 10);
$result->execute()->featchAll();
```

addExpression broke all, after this line phpStorm give me this warning: **Method 'condition' not found in string**

And in drupal log I have this error:  **Call to a member function condition() on string**

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that not all of the database API functions can be chained. Please have a read through [Database API Chaining](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/chaining) stating:

> Functions that cannot be chained:
>
> - `addExpression()`
> - `addField()`
> - `addJoin()`
> - `extend()`
> - `innerJoin()`
> - `join()`
> - `leftJoin()`
> - `rightJoin()`

The error you shared also indicates this as it appears that `condition()` errors after usage of `addExpression()` which doesn't return the database object.

So for your dynamic query it may be better to prepare a `$query` variable or so before assigning to `$result`:

```
$query = db_select('declarations', 'd');
$query->fields('d', array('agent_name', 'ifs_code', 'area_code'));
$query->addExpression('COUNT(id)', 'count');
$query->condition('fisccode', $fisccode);
...
$result = $query->execute()->featchAll();
```